# Top menu moves down when add some content

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

https://jsfiddle.net/c1kumo0y/

the top menu is moved a bit, and when scrolled the hero content is visible at the most top, when the following lines are removed:

```
<p id="firstLine">Projeniz mi var? Biz Yapalım</p></br>
<p id="secondLine">Projelerinizi en uygun fiyatlar la sizin yerinize Biz Yapalım</p>
```

the top menu becomes normal, what could possibly cause this? any help?

Comment: solved my problem by adding padding-top:100px; to  #mainContentDiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effect of margin collapsing:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing

> Margin collapsing happens wherever two (or more) top or bottom margins are touching. The basic idea is that when they touch, instead of getting the sum of the two margins, the bigger one is used, and the other is ignored.

There are many possible ways to fix your problem. For example you could add 1px padding to split the margins:

```
#container {
    padding-top: 1px;
}
```

Or you can insert some content. Or maybe find some other way more apropriate to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixedWidth {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1100px;
}
```

try this.